# Access non managed static member (native C++) from managed class C#/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, clr

I just started to work with CLI. In C++ we can access static memebers like className::static_field. But in case of using the unmanaged code from C#/ CLI... how do we access that?

I read some places that we need to make a DLL of the C++ project and use that in CLI/C#. For the Non static members I am able to use, using the process. But while using static I am seeing these errors...

```
unresolved token (0A0007CC) "public: static int unManaged::a" (?a@unManaged@@2HA)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int unManaged::a" (?a@unManaged@@2HA)
fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Sample UnManaged class..

```
class UnManaged {
int data;

static int a;
public:
UnManaged () {
    data = 0;
}
static int getStat() {
    return a;
}
static void setStat(int val) {
  a = val;
}
int getData() {
    return data;
}
void setData(int val) {
    data  = val;
}
};
```

I want to access from a CLI class like below...

```
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    UnManaged s;
    UnManaged ::setStat(25); //throwing linker error
    MessageBox::Show(System::Convert::ToString(s.getData()));
    s.setData(100);
    MessageBox::Show(System::Convert::ToString(s.getData()));
}
```

Comment: The code is not correct. You are missing `private` and `public` keywords in the unmanaged code. This is the first problem. The second problem is, that you should declare the `static int a;` in unmanaged code; e.g. `int UnManaged::a = 0;` *(outside of the `UnManaged` class)*. The last problem is, you should newer access to any members directly. Add a function that updates the static `a`, e.g. `setStat`.

Comment: After update: Since there is no `public` before `static int a;` this static member is private. Therefore you can not link it, since it is not exported.

Comment: Thanks @Julo . I had made the changes you suggested. But my main problem was how can we access the static members/functions of unmanaged from managed. I am still getting :: error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A000709) "private: static int UnManaged::a" (?a@UnManaged@@0HA)

Comment: You should not access a member directly. But when you need to access to a member, it must be public. In the code above it is not the case. Unfortunately I newer tested access to a member before, therefore I¨m not sure whether it will work as expected.

Comment: I think I am accessing the static members using member-functions, like setStat(x) . Still I am getting the same error.
(0A000709) "private: static int UnManaged::a" (?a@UnManaged@@0HA)

Comment: See my first comment. Have your somewhere in your C++ code line `int UnManaged::a = 0;`? When not, this is cause of your problem.

Comment: Forgetting to write the *definition* of a static C++ class member is a very traditional bug.  Everything is defined in a .h file, except that static member.  You need a .cpp file and link its output.  This is such a common bug that they [did something about](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) it in C++17.  If you use VS2017 then you can take advantage of it, even in a C++/CLI program.

Comment: Thanks Julo, and Hans for helping me out.